# spiting the values of CSV file if the content is also contains comma in bash or awk command

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

I am new to shell scripting and stuck with some assignment. I have a huge csv file as below :

```
"PT3","THE TORONTO-DOMINION BANK","2016-05-24T00:36:42Z","ANZ BANK NEW ZEALAND LIMITED","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","MAS,CA.ON.OSC,ASIC*,AAAA"
"xyz","THE TORONTO","2016-05-24T00:36:42Z","ANZ BANK NEW ZEALAND LIMITED","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","MAS,CA.ON.OSC,ASIC*,AAAA"
```

Here my requirement is that I want to make an array by splitting each row so that I can process on the data.

below is the code which I have written to process the data

```
while read line
do
    IFS=',' read -ra data <<< "$line"
    IFS=',' read -ra REPORTABLE_JURISDICTION_ARR <<< "${data[5]}"// split 5th column 
    IFS=$'\n' sorted=($(sort <<<"${REPORTABLE_JURISDICTION_ARR[*]}"))//sorting value
..processing the data.
```

But this is not giving the correct answer Because first `IFS=","` does not seems to be correct.

please help me with the correct Regex value for `IFS`

Comment: There's no way to make `IFS` a regex in `bash`. `bash` is probably not a good language for trying to parse CSV files.

Comment: Can you use Perl or Python or Ruby? These languages have proper CSV parsers. Any pure POSIX solution will have holes...

Comment: is there any awk command which can be used to replace comma with some other delimiter like pipe from 5th column

Comment: Does your actual data have the odd double double quotes in `""MAS,CA.ON.OSC,ASIC*,AAAA""`?

Comment: @dawg .. not is not double double..thats written by mistake. its simple "MAS,CA.ON.OSC,ASIC*,AAAA"

Comment: Please correct your example if you expect a correct solution.

Comment: @dawg .. python will help here .. can you please help me on that ?

Comment: You're probably thinking about this all wrong. You shouldn't be looking to do something to populate a shell array to further manipulate your data, you should just be using an awk script (or similar) to do it all in one place assuming "it all" is simply manipulating text, and if it's more than that then there's an excellent chance starting with a shell array is still the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` to swap out the delimiters (comma in this case) that occur within your double quotes with something else:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){ if(i%2==0) gsub(/,/, "|", $i)}} {print $0}' yourfile
```

Here awk is:

1. Setting the field separator and output field separator to double quote (`BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""}`)
2. Looping through each field that it finds (`{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i)`)
3. Testing the field ordinal's mod 2 to see if it is 0 (`if(i%2==0)`)
4. If it is even then it swaps out the semicolons with pipes (`gsub(/;/, "|", $i)`)
5. Prints out the transformed record (`{print $0}`)

In action:

```
>cat test
"PT3","THE TORONTO-DOMINION BANK","2016-05-24T00:36:42Z","ANZ BANK NEW ZEALAND LIMITED","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","MAS,CA.ON.OSC,ASIC*,AAAA"
"xyz","THE TORONTO","2016-05-24T00:36:42Z","ANZ BANK NEW ZEALAND LIMITED","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","MAS,CA.ON.OSC,ASIC*,AAAA"

>awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){ if(i%2==0) gsub(/,/, "|", $i)}} {print $0}' test
"PT3","THE TORONTO-DOMINION BANK","2016-05-24T00:36:42Z","ANZ BANK NEW ZEALAND LIMITED","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","MAS|CA.ON.OSC|ASIC*|AAAA"
"xyz","THE TORONTO","2016-05-24T00:36:42Z","ANZ BANK NEW ZEALAND LIMITED","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","MAS|CA.ON.OSC|ASIC*|AAAA"
```

---

If you want to just pull out data in that last comma for later parsing then you can employ the same `awk` trick by setting the FS to a double quote, then just pull out the second to last field:

```
awk -F"\"" '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

It's a lot more simple here since we are only tackling a single field, so you can go right to the thing you are after.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. the solution is perfectly correct. but now I want to replace those pipes again with comma, so how to do the same.I used the below command but did not work awk -F"\"" 'BEGIN{OFS="\""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){ if(i%2==0) gsub(/|/, ",", $i)}} {print $0}' temp2.csv ---> this is adding the comma after each character of each word ?

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ cat file.csv
"PT3","THE TORONTO-DOMINION BANK","2016-05-24T00:36:42Z","ANZ BANK NEW ZEALAND LIMITED","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","MAS,CA.ON.OSC,ASIC*,AAAA"
"xyz","THE TORONTO","2016-05-24T00:36:42Z","ANZ BANK NEW ZEALAND LIMITED","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","MAS,CA.ON.OSC,ASIC*,AAAA"
```

With POSIX `awk` you can replace the csv field separators with a pipe symbol like so:

```
$ awk  'BEGIN {FS="\"[^\"]\""} {s=""; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) s=s ? s "|" $i : $i; print s}' file.csv
"PT3|THE TORONTO-DOMINION BANK|2016-05-24T00:36:42Z|ANZ BANK NEW ZEALAND LIMITED|HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72|MAS,CA.ON.OSC,ASIC*,AAAA"
"xyz|THE TORONTO|2016-05-24T00:36:42Z|ANZ BANK NEW ZEALAND LIMITED|HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72|MAS,CA.ON.OSC,ASIC*,AAAA"
```

With `python`, which has a robust csv parser, you can do:

```
$ python -c 'import csv 
import fileinput

r=csv.reader(fileinput.input())

for row in r:
    print "|".join(row)' file.csv
PT3|THE TORONTO-DOMINION BANK|2016-05-24T00:36:42Z|ANZ BANK NEW ZEALAND LIMITED|HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72|MAS,CA.ON.OSC,ASIC*,AAAA
xyz|THE TORONTO|2016-05-24T00:36:42Z|ANZ BANK NEW ZEALAND LIMITED|HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72|MAS,CA.ON.OSC,ASIC*,AAAA
```

Either of those solutions produce lines of pipe separated fields for further use in Bash.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any awk command which can be used to replace comma with some other delimiter like pipe from 5th column.

Using `FPAT` in `gnu-awk`, you can do this:

```
awk -v OFS=';' -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' '{
   s=$1; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) s = s (i <= 5 ? "," : "|") $i; print s}' file.csv

"PT3","THE TORONTO-DOMINION BANK","2016-05-24T00:36:42Z","ANZ BANK NEW ZEALAND LIMITED","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72"|"MAS,CA.ON.OSC,ASIC*,AAAA"
"xyz","THE TORONTO","2016-05-24T00:36:42Z","ANZ BANK NEW ZEALAND LIMITED","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72"|"MAS,CA.ON.OSC,ASIC*,AAAA
```